# SQLite3 check for values in database in python

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

Currently having issues getting the proper SQL commands for this example below.

```
title  || stock        || ids         ||
----------------------------------------
item 1 || low-stock    || 883864-1096 ||
item 1 || out-of-stock || 883864-1097 ||
item 1 || out-of-stock || 883864-1098 ||
item 2 || out-of-stock || 883864-1456 ||
```

The ideal is when i refresh the API json, if value in the stock column changes for that id on a new request i wish to update the database to that new value.So what would be the proper SQL command? I attempted the following: 
(function to refresh api and parse values)

```
stocklevels = stocklevels
title= title
ids = ids
z = (title,)
c.execute('SELECT (title) FROM products WHERE title=?', z)
olderstock = old_stock = c.fetchone()
```

so far, Where title=?  commands grabs the title, however, after that i am lost. 
All help is appreciated

---

```
def loadjson():
   r = sess.get(url)
   data = r.json()
   x = data['skus']
   title = data['name']
   for l in x:
      stocklevels = l['stockLevel']
    ids = l['id']
    postit(stocklevels,title,ids)

def postit(stocklevels,title,ids):
  stocklevels = stocklevels
  title= title
  ids = ids
  conn = sqlite3.connect('ports.db')
  c = conn.cursor()
  c.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS products(title TEXT,stock TEXT,ids INTERGER UNIQUE)""")
  try:
     c.execute("""INSERT INTO products (title,stock,ids) VALUES (?,?,?)""", (title,stocklevels,ids,))
  except:
      try:
       # SQL command to select rows with same title.
       # If Stocklevels != Stock  AKA if new stocklevels parsed on r  doesnt  == stock column
       # c.execute Update stocklevel
       # else pass


    except Exception as e:
        print e
```

Comment: Are you just asking how to select all three columns `title, stock, ids` instead of just the one column `(title)`?

Comment: Or are you asking how to write an `UPDATE` statement with the same `WHERE` clause as your existing `SELECT`?

Comment: The powerhouses in SQL are SELECT, UPDATE, INSERT, and DELETE. SELECT let's you LOOK at records in your database. UPDATE let's you EDIT records in your database. INSERT let's you put in NEW records into your database. DELETE let's you delete records from your database. In this case you want to update a value, so you need to use an UPDATE statement instead of a SELECT statement.

Comment: I am asking how how to compare stock column per IDs and title vs when i make a new requests. So when it changes say from low-stock to out of stock for that title and id it changes in the database .

Comment: It is not clear what you try to achive. Try to explain what you want to achieve in the form like. I have records R1, R2, ..., RN in the database (this you have already in the question), then the operation named X with parameters A, B and C is executed. The data in database becomes T1, T2, ..., TN. The operation turns result R. Currently from the explanation it is not clear even if the operation is read-only (so that it calculates some value and does not change the db) or it modifies the database. If you provide the name of the operation and params (if any) to give some context, that would help

Comment: @RomanKonoval to dumb it down, i am just trying to compare the stock column for each row every time i request the api.

Comment: Sorry, it is still not clear and your explanation in the comment above does not help.

Comment: @RomanKonoval i updated posted with notes to help understand